# Select rows that satisfy a certain group condition in psql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Given the following table:

```
 id  |  value 
  ---+---------
  1  |    1 
  1  |    0
  1  |    3
  2  |    1
  2  |    3
  2  |    5
  3  |    2 
  3  |    1
  3  |    0
  3  |    1
```

I want the following table:

```
 id  |  value 
  ---+---------
  1  |    1 
  1  |    0
  1  |    3
  3  |    2 
  3  |    1
  3  |    0
  3  |    1
```

The table contains `ids` that have a minimum `value` of 0.
I have tried using `exist` and `having` but to no success.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
select * from foo where id in (SELECT id FROM foo GROUP BY id HAVING MIN(value) = 0)
```

or that ( with window functions)

```
select * from 
 (select *,min(value) over (PARTITION BY id) min_by_id from foo) a 
where min_by_id=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it's a fairly simple `having` clause:

```
=# SELECT id, MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM foo GROUP BY id HAVING MIN(value) = 0;
 id | min | max 
----+-----+-----
  1 |   0 |   3
  3 |   0 |   2
(2 rows)
```

Did I miss something that is making it more complicated?

Comment: I actually want all the entries with id = 1 and id = 3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it is not possible to use window function in WHERE or HAVING. Below is solution based on JOINs.

1. JOIN every row with all rows of the same id.
2. Filter based on second set.
3. Show result from first set.

The SQL looks like this.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a_table AS a
INNER JOIN a_table AS value ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.value = 0;
```

Comment: you have to add a distinct because if you have more than one value 0 for one id, the result will be duplicated

Comment: If there is more than one 0 for one id, there are duplicated rows in the source table. It is a different problem.

Comment: yes  but there are duplicated rows in the exemple ( id 3 value 1 ) , it's not very pretty but not forbiden.Perhaps there's another real unique id , I don't know and it's not important , so effectivly a distinct will not correct because we have to keep duplicated rows but your request duplicates more the result. Exemple if you add values (4,0),(4,0),(4,1) your request will return 6 rows with id=4 -> it's not true